# parse error unexpected '' '' T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with my PHP, I'm trying to create the empty space to make it seperate with other variable, but i'm getting an parse error unexpected '' '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'.

Here is where the error are jumping on this line:

```
echo '<span id="time1">'.$time1.'</span> - <span id="title1">'.$programme1.' ' ' '.$programme1a.'</span><br><br>';
```

Here is the PHP

```
<?php
$links = $row['links'];
$html = file_get_html($links);

$base = $row['links'];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($str);

//output1
$title1 = $html->find('li[id=row1-1]', 0)->plaintext; // with this
$title1 = preg_split("/ {4,}/",$title1);

$time1 = $title1[1];
$programme1 = $title1[2];
$programme1a = $title1[3];


echo '<span id="time1">'.$time1.'</span> - <span id="title1">'.$programme1.' ' ' '.$programme1a.'</span><br><br>';
?>
```

Does anybody know how I can create the space in the echo to allow me to make it seperate with other variable?

The reason I'm doing this is because i have got the output which it show looks like this:

```
9:00 PM - NCIS"Alleged"
```

I'm trying to make it looks like this:

```
9:00 PM - NCIS "Alleged"
```

Comment: `.$programme1.' ' ' '.$programme1a.` ??

Comment: Look at `' ' ' '` and try to explain to yourself what it does.

Comment: why put this topic as on hold? what a idiot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide space then can use `&nbsp;`

```
echo '<span id="time1">'.$time1.'</span> - <span id="title1">'.$programme1.'&nbsp;'.$programme1a.'</span><br><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
$programme1.'  '.$programme1a
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/137150):

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
$a= "blah";
$b="blah";
echo $a."    ".$b;
```

**Program output:**

> blah    blah

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
echo "<span id='time1'>$time1</span> - <span id='title1'>$programme1 $programme1a</span><br /><br />\n";
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response everyone, I'm very appreciated that you all understood what I really wanted. Problem solved!